# Golang добавление данных в byte slice с отмеченным размером

Tags: golang

Как можно добавить данные в слайс с отмеченным размером `[16]byte`?

Есть ключ который нужно распарсить, ключ по размерам не должен превышать 32 байта.

```
var firstOffset [16]byte 
var secondOffset [16]byte

result := make([][]byte, 32)
result = bytes.Split([]byte(key), []byte(":"))

for i := range result {
    if i < 16 && i != 0 {
        firstOffset = append(firstOffset, result[i])
    } else { 
        secondOffset = append(secondOffset, result[i])
    }
}
```

То есть ключ делит на две части, первая - 16 байт и вторая 16 байт, если индекс `i` до 16 или равняется 16 -> добавляет в первый слайс `firstOffset` с отмеченным размером, иначе -> добавляет во второй слайс `secondOffset` с отмеченным размером. Но это не работает, и как я понял из-за того что размер слайса отмеченный, если же слайс был бы N размеров `[]byte` всё бы работало, но можно ли как-то это исправить? Мне нужно именно добавлять во слайс с отмеченным размером.

Answer (score 3):

Либо это слайс `[]T` либо массив фиксированного размера `[N]T`. Дело в том, что массивы

```
var (
    a [9]int
    b [0]struct{}
    s = [...]string{"one","two", "three"}
)
```

имеют фиксированный размер. Т.е. как-то расширить их нельзя. Можно сказать, что массив - это что-то вроде структуры с доступом по индексу. Например для структуры

```
type User struct {
    Name string
    Age int
}
```

доступ к полю `Age`, это доступ к User + смещение Age. И то же самое касается массивов. Только смещение там определяется не именем поля, а индексом.

Чтобы изменить размер массива, из него нужно сделать слайс (кусок по-русски) и работать уже со слайсом.

```
var (
    ary [12]int // массив фиксированного размера

    slice     = ary[:]  // слайс на основе этого массива
    firstPart = ary[:6] // первая часть
    firstPart = ary[6:] // вторая часть
)
```

Пример на [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/NXAmgA0joWM).

Таким образом расширить массив нельзя, но можно сделать из него слайс и работать с ним с помощью `copy` и `append`.

---

Чтобы изменить содержимое массива, можно пройтись по индексу или (что рекомендую) использовать `copy`, который отлично подходит для Вашего примера.

```
i := bytes.Index(key, []byte(":"))
if i < 0 {
    fmt.Println("error ':' not found in key")
    return
}
copy(fp[:], key[:i])
copy(sp[:], key[i+1:])
```

Пример на [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/elk64LDJHeg). Как видите, `copy` работает со слайсами `fp[:]` и `sp[:]`, которые в своей основе имеют массивы `fp` и `sp` соответственно.

---

По своей сути, слайс это структура вида

```
type slice struct {
    arrayPinter *T
    len         int
    cap         int
}
```

т.е. слайс имеет указатель на массив, длину куска и его ёмкость. В общем случае, создание и работа с этим подлежащим массивом скрыта от разработчика. По сути

```
t := make([]byte, 10, 20)
```

создаёт массив размером 20 (может больше), и возвращает слайс указывающий на него.

В случае же, с `fp[:]` создаётся слайс, который указывает на массив `fp`. И копирование в этот слайс `copy(fp[:], key[:i])` по факту, копирует в массив.

---

[copy](https://godoc.org/builtin#copy) | [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Answer (score 0):

Счёт начинается с нуля. 
Это:

```
} else { 
    secondOffset = append(secondOffset, result[i])
}
```

Замените на:

```
} else { 
    secondOffset = append(secondOffset, result[i-15])
}
```